# Get website filename without extension using php

Tags: php

I would like to get a website's filename after domain without the extension in this way:

```
website URL: www.domain.co.uk/xyz.php
```

I need to dynamically get this part:

```
xyz
```

without .php and without all the domain before. **Please note that this will be applied to many pages on the website so "xyz" is just an example and there will be many different filenames.**

I have this code, which allows me to get the whole URL, but I don't know how to separate the requested part:

```
"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

I want to use this part later in setting a background so it will be implemented into the style in this way:

```
<style>
  .parall {background: url("img/xyz.jpg") right top no-repeat;}
</style>
```

As you can notice above - the "speakers-hire" phrase has been taken from the url and implemented into the style. How to combine all of this?

Thanks

Comment: Hey! any particular reason I got downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

Use basename function with parse_url to get filename from url

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.co.uk/abc.php?def=xyz';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); 
$file_name = basename($path,".php");
```

For background url in style tag you can use preg_match

```
$input="parall {background: url("img/xyz.jpg") right top n";

preg_match('/url\("(.*)"\)/', $input, $output);

$file_name = basename($output[1],".jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks @SachinPatil4991 I will check that out. How to implement this into the background url?

Answer (score 0):

Hello for apply this url in your css code:
**Your file must be a .php file**

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.domain.co.uk/abc.php?def=xyz';
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); 
    $file_name = basename($path,".php");
?>

<style>
    .parall {background: <?php echo $file_name;?> right top no-repeat;}
</style>
```